# Vaadin Grid custom TextArea editor is not being fully shown

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have defined a custom editor for my Vaadin 7 Grid

```
longColumn.setEditorField(getTextArea());
```

where getTextArea() is:

```
private Field<?> getTextArea() {
   TextArea ta=new TextArea();
   ta.setWidth("300px");
   ta.setHeight("200px");
   return ta;
}
```

The TextArea appears to be of the given size, but it is cut to the height of the row, and is completely unusable.

[image]

Is there any way to make the editor to be bigger in order to use a TextArea that big?

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom height via CSS by adding a new style using setRowStyleGenerator() to the Grid.

Comment: Do you know any example? This would change the row size always or only while being edited?